# Broken image with readfile and file_get_contents

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents, readfile

I'm trying to use a function in order to get this working:

```
<img src='login.php?image=ind_legend.jpg'>
```

But I can't pass through the function to place the image. I went back a couple of steps and tried only this part of the code:

```
<?php
$file = "http://localhost/sales/test.jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
?>
```

or using this function:

```
echo file_get_contents($source);
```

but the fact is that the only thing I get is a broken image cross (IE) or nothing in Firefox.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly have some whitespace in your PHP script, or a [`UTF-8 BOM`](http://www.google.com/search?q=UTF-8%20BOM) invisibly before your `<?php` opening marker. Use a hexeditor to find out.

To debug it further, open the image URL http://localhost/login.php?image=ind_legend.jpg directly in your browser, save the file. And then compare it to the original JPEG.

Answer (score 18):

use the **ob_clean()** function of php before the **readfile()**

Comment: This is a way of working around the issue, the actual resolution of issue is in accepted anwser.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, you probably have some whitespace. I'd try replacing the entire file with the code below. Removing the closing php statement eliminates any chance that there is extra whitespace:

```
<?php
$file = "http://localhost/sales/test.jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all point your browser to http://youraddress/login.php?image=ind_legend.jpg and check the result.

Maybe the file /sales/test.jpg is corrupted or you don't have enabled the http:// wrapper for readline

At last save the corrupted image via the save image as... context menu option of your browser of choice and try to open it with a text editor. I will not surprised if you will find an error message (if you have them enabled).