# PHP readfile() not working

Tags: php

I can't get readfile() to work. Trying to display an image. I have this in a page caled 'getImage.php'

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/test.jpg");
?>
```

I've tried using a relative path of just 
    readfile("images/test.jpg");

I still get a broken image, When viewing the source code the image source shows:
    site.co.uk/getImage.php

When I remove the header I get page full of weird symbols and letters.

What am I doing wrong? Could this be a config in the php.ini file? Am on shared hosting, so not sure I can amend it. Have also tried file_get_contents() but still can't display image.

Image size is 242 KB.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please echo the path `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/test.jpg";` and check is that correct?

Comment: Make sure that your php file doesn't have BOM marker at the beginning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877138/broken-image-with-readfile-and-file-get-contents

Comment: You should *always* check if [file exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), and if it does, set proper  headers when outputting image contents, the most important one:
`header('Content-type: image/jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

'When I remove the header I get page full of weird symbols and letters.'  It sounds like its working to me.  readfile will open the file and read whats inside and display it in the output buffer.  Image files are not text files so the weird symbols and letters your seeing is similar to what you would see if you opened the file in a text editor. Where are you trying to display this image in an html file?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / from front of images and see ? Like this ...

`<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."images/test.jpg");
?>`