# Getting weird characters from image after htaccess redirect

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to get the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` of the viewer after viewing the image by a script.

Here is the directory

```
/www
|-- /other.org
|-- /example.com
    |-- /sub
        |-- .htaccess
        |-- agentlog.php
        |-- /i
            |-- photo.png
```

I have separated the image files and the script to different folders. The root of all the files is in the subdirectory of the domain. So `http://example.com/sub`, the images are stored at `http://example.com/sub/i`. The `.htaccess` file will redirect all images to a PHP file which gets the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and stores it in a database and also display the image through a subdomain which will not be redirected by the `.htaccess`.

In more detail, the user types in `http://example.com/sub/photo.png` to the browser, to the viewer it will just look like that's the image and the viewer will not notice anything else or any redirection. However, what happens when the user types in is that

The `.htaccess` will check if `photo.png` exists in  `http://example.com/sub/i/photo.png`, and redirect the request to a file named `agentlog.php` at `http://example.com/sub/agentlog.php` if the image exists and then `agentlog.php` will log and save to the database and show the `photo.png` through `http://i.example.com/photo.png` where `http://i.example.com` points to `/www/sub/i`.

Here is the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^i\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/i/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ agentlog.php [NC,L]
```

Here is the `agentlog.php` file without the sql code

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ext = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = basename($path);

header("Content-Type: image/$ext");

$img = "http://i.example.com/$filename";
readfile($img);
```

Everything works well except the image doesn't actually show itself, the `.htaccess` redirects. It shows

```
�PNG  IHDR�^���� �IDATx��ݯ��u���............
```

and not the actual image itself.

If I directly access the image, it works fine so I think the problem lies in the `.htaccess` but I do not know what other rule to write that can make this work.

If another further information is needed I will be glad to add in. How do I solve this? Or are there any methods to go about doing this? I have already put in the Content Header but not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a request - why not change `readfile("the url")` to `readfile("file_path")`? Just try, as I never use readfile for URL before, although the document mentioned it's possible.

Comment: @LionelChan Hi, I tried and there is no difference, I still get the word version of the image.

Comment: Can you print `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` from PHP code and tell is what you get

Comment: @anubhava Hi, the document root is like that DOCUMENT_ROOT: /home/user/public_html/sites/example.com

Comment: Then condition should be `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/i/$1 -f`

Comment: @anubhava Im sorry, but I misread your reply, but the result is still the same. The redirection part is working except the image displaying part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using closing tag `?>`check, if there is any white-space or newline character afterwards. Omitting closing tag is considered as a good practice.

**Edits**

Try this:-

```
        $img = "http://i.example.com/$filename";
        header("Content-Type: image/$ext");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img)); 
        ob_clean(); // Clean (erase) the output buffer.
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer.
        readfile($img); // Output the file to browser.
        exit; // Stop execution of the script
```

Comment: Hi there is not whitespace or newline, I have omitted the closing tag and there's no difference, the image still wont show.

Comment: Add on: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877138/broken-image-with-readfile-and-file-get-contents

Comment: @LionelChan Hi, I have tried that, still the same. I still do not know what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks!! I found out that one of my other SQL files had a white space that was linked to it! Had me thinking for so long!! I removed it and it was working!!

Comment: @pleasega, m glad u found it.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works well except the image doesn't actually show itself,
>    the .htaccess redirects. It shows
>
> `�PNG  IHDR�^���� �IDATx��ݯ��u���............`

It's a header's error (mime type error) -  text/plain instead of image/...

Anyway your .htaccess does not work in my environment
It should be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ agentlog.php [NC,L]
```

And PHP code can be something like this

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ext = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = basename($path);

header("Content-Type: image/".$ext);

readfile($filename);
?>
```