# Image output not working php

Tags: php

I have a weird behaviour in a class I'm using. 
The class resize an image and outputs it. The relevant code is as follow:

```
// output the image
header("Content-Disposition: filename={$output};");
header("Content-Type: {$info["mime"]}");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');

readfile($output);
```

The result is this bizarre little square:

[image: http://puu.sh/oMWnZ/336c6356cf.png]

And the HTML as follow:

```
 <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/tv-tracker/images/media/2/backdrop-100x100.jpg">
```

Any help would be well appreciated!

Comment: problem with `header("Content-Type: {$info["mime"]}");`

Comment: I suspect the error reporting and the response from the server are indicating a syntax error.  Don't just look at the "image" on the webpage, look at the actual server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misuse of `"`, Nested use occurs the problem, just Change your Content type of the given header.

```
header("Content-Type: {$info["mime"]}");
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: {$info['mime']}");
```

Example:

```
$output = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';
header("Content-Disposition: filename={$output};");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');

readfile($output);
```

Comment: Changed this but it still didn't work. I added obclean() before readfile() and it's not working (as suggested there http://stackoverflow.com/a/28479155/2432113 )

Comment: As my example, i got this working, and i found only one error. you can also check the example given by me, May be you have some server issue..